# Change pricing based on whether checkbox is checked or not in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to calculate some shipping prices in Laravel. There are only two options based on weight and I have that working with an if/else statement. The client would like to add an option that if someone would like to ship their items faster and they are under the Priority weight, they can for the additional shipping cost. I set up a checkbox in my blade template but am not 100% sure how to implement it. I would assume I have to do some kind if isset statement.

Here is the code in my blade template:

```
@if( $total_weight <= 16.00)
            <li class="payment__item">
                <label for="priority">Priority Mail</label>
                <span style="padding-top: 2.5%;">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="priority" value="1" {{ $shipping_cost['attributes']['priority'] == '10' ? 'checked="checked"' : '1'}} >
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="payment__item">Total:
                <span>${{ number_format($payment_total + $shipping_cost, 2, '.', '')}} </span>
            </li>
            @else
            <li class="payment__item">Total: <span>${{ number_format($payment_total + 10, 2, '.', '')}} </span>
        </li>
        @endif
```

And in my controller I have this for my public function:

```
public function showPayment() {
    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    $payment_info = Session::get('payment_info');


    if($payment_info['status'] == 'on_hold' ) {
         $total_weight = $cart->totalWeight;
         // $shipping_cost = $cart->totalPrice + 5;
         $sales_tax = $cart->totalPrice * .085 ;
         $payment_total = $cart->totalPrice + $sales_tax;

        return view('cart.payments', ['payment_info' => $payment_info, 'cartItems' => $cart, 'sales_tax' => $sales_tax, 'shipping_cost' => $shipping_cost, 'total_weight'=>$total_weight, 'payment_total' => $payment_total]);

    }else{
        return redirect()->route("home");
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit here is the data that is being passed

[image: Payment Info]

[image: Payment Total]

[image: Sales Tax]

[image: Weight]

Comment: Is this checkbox is always available or it should be only visible when they have price more than 10. Second one is when we need to auto check this?

Comment: It is only available for the first option.  It is based on weight, so if it is under 16 they will have the option for standard shipping or upgrade shipping.

Comment: @JitendraYadav do you know what I am doing wrong here? Maybe I am going about it all wrong,

Comment: please provide me data that you're passing to blade. just do a `dd($data)` . Use your array name and add that to question. Will be able to help you. I got your query now. Just give me the input data

Comment: @JitendraYadav I have a few arrays that are passing data. Would you like to see them all? They build on each other to get the pricing.

Comment: @JitendraYadav would you like me to add the data to the original question? I don't see another place to put it. Let me know.

Comment: yes dude, atleast all data that is being used here, if not others.

Comment: @JitendraYadav I added all the data here. The images are in this order: payment_info, payment_total, sales_tax, weight. Let me know if that is all that you need. Thanks.

Comment: @JitendraYadav do you think that this whole process would be better dealt with using Javascript or something like Vue?

Comment: For initial rendering, blade is okay, but if they check the checkbox and price should change , then definitely we will require javascript to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to check if the checkbox is checked. If it is, then add the priority shipping cost to the total

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

function check() {
    var a = input.checked ? "{{$payment_info['price'] + number_format($sales_tax, 2, '.', '') + 10 }}" : "{{$payment_info['price'] + number_format($sales_tax, 2, '.', '') + 5 }}   ";
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '$ ' + a;
}
input.onchange = check;
check();
```